# Every supremum is a limit point.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

So I found this problem in Abbot's book, introduction to real analysis, it says "show that if A is a bounded set, then supA is a limit point", my argument is as it follows:

This is not true, take for example $A=\left\{\frac1n, n>0\right\}$, then 1 is clearly the supremum of this set, as it's its maximum, but 1 is an isolated point and hence can not be a limit point.

Also take $(0,1)\cup\{4\}$. Clearly bounded and its supremum is also an isolated point, my guess is the book was trying to say "take A as an open and bounded set".

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: take also {1,2}, clearly bounded by 2, its supremum is 2, but 2 is not a limit point.

Comment: There is no standard definition of limit point, so it depends on Abbot's definition.

Comment: Two equivalent definitions: a limit point, x,  is such if and only if there is a sequence a_n!=x for all n, such that the limit (convergence) of said sequence is x. 
Second one: A limit point is such if there exists an epsilon neighborhood such that the intersecction of said point with the whole set is never empty.

Comment: I wonder if the text wasn't claiming if $\sup A \not \in A$ then $A$ is a limit point.

Comment: So far as I could find Abott's *Understanding* Analysis had the following Excercises: Exercise 3.2.11. Let A be bounded above so that s = sup A exists. Show that
s ∈ A.
Exercise 3.2.12. Decide whether the following statements are true or false.
Provide counterexamples for those that are false, and supply proofs for those
that are true.
(a) For any set A ⊆ R, Ac is open.
(b) If a set A has an isolated point, it cannot be an open set.
(c) A set A is closed if and only if A = A.
(d) If A is a bounded set, then s = sup A is a limit point of A.
(e) Every finite set is closed.
...
tbc...

Comment: .... So exercise 3.2.11 says if $A$ is bounded above then $\sup A$ is in the *closure* of $A$.  And exercise 32.12 d) is your statement but it *isn't* asking you to prove it.  It is asking you if it is true or false.  In that case the answer is it is false for the reason you gave.  3.2.11 is pertainant as it says that $\sup A$ is in the closure of $A$ and so is *EITHER* a limit point OR a non-limit point of $A$.  An isolated point of $A$ is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any one-point (or indeed, any non-empty, finite) set provides an instant counterexample to the claim as stated. However, if we add the condition that the set also be open, that fixes it!

More generally, given any bounded set $A$ with non-empty interior, the supremum of the interior of $A$ is a limit point of $A.$

**Edit**: Even *more* generally, and possibly what Abbott was going for, if $A$ is a bounded set without a(n isolated) maximum element, then the supremum of $A$ is a limit point of $A.$

Comment: TOTALLY, even if not finite like (0,1)U{2}, proves to be a counterexample, thank you very much.

Comment: What if it's the discrete topology?

Comment: @AndrewZhang we're dealing with real topology, hence the tag "Real Analysis."

Comment: FWIW IMO making the condition the set by open is unnecessarily strong.  I'd say the condition that $\sup A$ is not an isolated point of $A$ (and not necessarily any point of $A$ at all) then $\sup A$ is a limit point makes for a more applicable result.  But that's is (literally) just an opinion.

Comment: @fleablood, that's totally fair. It seemed overly strong to me, too.